# get the form1 value by submiting form2 to django view

Tags: python, html, django, forms

I have 2 forms "form 1" and "form2".

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" value="text" name="txt" id="txt" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>

<form method="get" id='myfo'>
    <input type="text" value="text" name="txt1" id="txt1" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

in my `view.py` code,

```
if request.GET:
    // Here I can get the vaule of txt1 from form 2 
    data=request.GET.get('txt1')
    #do some operations here.
```

I if enter some values in txt - form1 . I won't submit the "form 1". When submitting "form 2", I want the "form 1" txt value accessible in the view code.

Comment: I don't get it...are you wanting to pass a value from form 1 to form 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking is impossible. Each form submits its input fields independently, so fields in "form 1" will never show in "form 2".

Instead, setup your HTML Form correctly, and you'll have both as accessible:

```
<form method="post" >
    <input type="text" value="text" name="txt" id="txt" />
    <input type="text" value="text" name="txt1" id="txt1" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```